# what does a single colon mean in sbt (between two commands)

Tags: sbt, travis-ci

In a .travis.yml file using sbt, I see this

```
script:
  - sbt ++$TRAVIS_SCALA_VERSION test:fastOptJS test:fullOptJS
```

In sbt, I can run `test`, and I can run `fastOptJS` . What does the single colon between them do?

In travis, can one run a sequence of commands? ie. what does it mean for   `test:fastOptJS` to be followed by `test:fullOptJS`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In sbt, I can run `test`, and I can run `fastOptJS` . What does the single colon between them do?

`test:fastOptJS` means `fastOptJS` in `test` scope. The confusion comes from the fact that the test scope and the test task are both `test` in sbt's shell.

This, btw, is fixed in sbt 1.1's new "unified slash syntax" where the test scope now `Test`, so `test:fastOptJS` is now `Test / fastOptJS`.

> In travis, can one run a sequence of commands? ie. what does it mean for `test:fastOptJS` to be followed by test:fullOptJS?

Yes you can run a sequence of commands.

`sbt ++$TRAVIS_SCALA_VERSION test:fastOptJS test:fullOptJS` means run `++$TRAVIS_SCALA_VERSION` (which changes `scalaVersion`), then `test:fastOptJS` then `test:fullOptJS`.