# What's the difference between :, :: and / in SBT?

Tags: sbt

I was trying to recall whether it was `test:compile`, `test::compile` or `test/compile` that I wanted while doing something on SBT, when it struck me that though I have some intuition on which separator to use for what, I don't have a clear notion of what each separator is used for.

So, when typing tasks on the sbt console, when/for what do I use `:`, `::` and `/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Different separators](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Inspecting-Settings.html#Task-specific+Settings) were used for different [scope axis](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scopes.html#Scope+axes):

- single colon `:` follows a configuration axis
- double colon `::` follows a task axis
- slash `/` follows a subproject axis

However these have been unified by **slash syntax**: [Unification of sbt shell notation and build.sbt DSL](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/unification-of-sbt-shell-notation-and-build-sbt-dsl/913) discussion led to  [Unify sbt shell and build.sbt syntax (scope path syntax) #3434](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/3434) which released in [1.1.0](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/tag/v1.1.0) slash syntax

```
<project-id>/<config-ident>/intask/key
```

corresponding to

```
<project-id>/config:intask::key
```

hence, for example,

```
show root/Compile/compile/scalacOptions
```

corresponds to

```
show root/compile:compile::scalacOptions
```

Related question: [what does a single colon mean in sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48324113/5205022)